# Refactoring couple of identical methods using static content

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

So right now I have two basically identical methods each populating an attribute of my object.

Right now I am populating my model like this

```
        ConfigModel model = new ConfigModel();
        model.ConfigVarName = PopulateVarName(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.ConfigVarDesc = PopulateDescriptions(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.ConfigVarMaxValue = PopulateVarMaxValue(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.ConfigVarMinValue = PopulateVarMinValue(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.ConfigVarEngUnit = PopulateVarEngUnit(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.ConfigVarFormat = PopulateVarFormat(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.ConfigVarType = PopulateVarType(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.IOReference = PopulateIOReferences(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        model.TemplateName = PopulateTemplateName(firstDataRow);
        model.TagName = PopulateTagName(firstDataRow);
        model.SecurityGroup = PopulateSecurityGroup(firstDataRow);
        model.Area = PopulateArea(firstDataRow);
        model.Container = PopulateContainer(firstDataRow);
        model.ContainedName = PopulateContainedName(firstDataRow);
```

but calling each this many times doesn't feel right. Here's the giblet of the methods

```
    public List<string> PopulateVarName(List<int> boxSize, int firstDataRow)
    {
        List<string> names;
        string startCellForName = StaticColumns.configVarName + firstDataRow;
        int lastRowOfActualData = CalculateLastDataRowForInstance(firstDataRow, boxSize[0]);
        string fullRange = startCellForName + ":" + StaticColumns.configVarName + lastRowOfActualData;
        Xcl.Range rng = sheet.Range[fullRange];
        names = PopulateList(rng);
        return names;
    }
```

and

```
public string PopulateTagName(int firstDataRow)
    {

        string tagNameCell = StaticColumns.tagName + firstDataRow;
        string tagName = sheet.Range[tagNameCell].Value2;

        return tagName;
    }
```

So any advisory to get rid of these many lines and methods would be appreciated

Comment: put `StaticColumns.configVarName` to paramter ?

Comment: I was hoping there were some sort of loop-solution to these situations I just couldn't wrap my head around

Comment: This looks fine

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two methods, which do not look "basically identical" to me, you should put all your member variable initialization into the constructor of your class:

```
class ConfigModel
{
    public ConfigModel(List<int> boxSize, int firstDataRow)
    {
        ConfigVarName = PopulateVarName(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        ConfigVarDesc = PopulateDescriptions(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        ConfigVarMaxValue = PopulateVarMaxValue(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        ConfigVarMinValue = PopulateVarMinValue(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        ConfigVarEngUnit = PopulateVarEngUnit(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        ConfigVarFormat = PopulateVarFormat(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        ConfigVarType = PopulateVarType(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        IOReference = PopulateIOReferences(boxSize, firstDataRow);
        TemplateName = PopulateTemplateName(firstDataRow);
        TagName = PopulateTagName(firstDataRow);
        SecurityGroup = PopulateSecurityGroup(firstDataRow);
        Area = PopulateArea(firstDataRow);
        Container = PopulateContainer(firstDataRow);
        ContainedName = PopulateContainedName(firstDataRow);
    }
}
```

And then create your model class like this

```
ConfigModel model = new ConfigModel(boxSize, firstDataRow);
```

EDIT:
From the comments I suggest to do something like

```
Populate(List<int> boxSize, int firstDataRow, int category)
{
    [...]
    string fullRange;
    switch (category) 
    {
        case 1:
            fullRange = startCellForName + ":" + StaticColumns.configVarName + lastRowOfActualData;
            break;
        case 2:
            fullRange = startCellForName + ":" + StaticColumns.ConfigVarDesc + lastRowOfActualData; 
            break;

        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I meant that I had two kind of methods. The ones taking one parameter and the ones taking two, and each method under each category is basically identical. I would like not to have 9 basically identical methods and I'm asking if there's a solution I can't come up with

Comment: @IDR and where exactly do these methods differ? If they are identical you can use only one of them for all method calls

Comment: In what static value they are calling. The only difference is between StaticColumns.configVarName and StaticColumns.ConfigVarDesc etc

Comment: @IDR if i understand it right you could just add a new parameter to your method like 'bool is_var_name' and then do an if-else statement in your method where to decide, which StaticColumns. to choose

Comment: @IDR I made an edit on my answer with an switch-case example

Comment: Yeah I like that much more than having 10 almost identical methods.